# c-mode single quote fontification

Tags: emacs, font-lock, emacs-semantic

I just noticed that single quotes are being font-locked with warning face, throwing off fontification of the entire buffer.  Does anyone know why this is is happening?  For example,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  if ( getc( stdin ) == '\n' )
               //why is ^ getting font-lock-warning-face?
    ;

  return 0;
}
```

Version info: emacs 26.0.50, semantic version 2.2.
Started with `emacs -Q`, then enabling semantic mode, `M-x semantic-mode` in the buffer.

Comment: This is probably more of an Emacs problem (software related) than a programming one per-se. That looks like valid code.

Comment: @tadman yea it is, I think recent change to cc-mode that I just noticed but not sure.  I included C code for reproducible example

Comment: Try https://emacs.stackexchange.com/